# How to make a block that gives you points in Roblox

Tags: roblox

I have a leaderboard in one script. This is my code:

```
print("Cash Leaderboard Loaded")


function onPlayerEntered(newPlayer)

    local stats = Instance.new("IntValue")
    stats.Name = "leaderstats"

    local cash = Instance.new("IntValue")
    cash.Name = "Money"       --name of currency (e.g. cash, money,     resources, bucks, etc.)
    cash.Value = 50      --starting money.

    cash.Parent = stats
    stats.Parent = newPlayer
end
game.Players.ChildAdded:connect(onPlayerEntered)
```

I am trying to make it so when you click a block, it gives you more money.
The code is in a different script. [image]

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure!

```
local CD = script.Parent
local Amount_To_Give = 10
CD.MouseClick:Connect(function(plr)
    plr:WaitForChild('leaderstats').Money.Value = plr:WaitForChild('leaderstats').Money.Value + Amount_To_Give
end)
```

Comment: This answer is incredibly vague, you don't explain anything about the script or give any references to why or how your script works.  You should try giving more detailed answers in the future.

Comment: tl;dr
I respect your detailed response, and I apologize for what I did wrong.